# How to make field readonly based on group and state with _get_view function. Odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

I want to use the _get_view function in the 'purchase.order'  to set readonly attribute of some customs fields based on group and state.
Here is my code. It works with group condition:

```
@api.model
    def _get_view(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', **options):
        arch, view = super()._get_view(view_id, view_type, **options)
        rec_list = ['new_field1', 'new_field2', 'new_field3']
        for field in arch.xpath("//field"):
            if field.get('name') in rec_list:
                field.set('readonly', '1') if self.env.user.has_group('base.user_admin') else field.set('readonly', '0')
        return arch, view
```

My problem is how to get the actuel value of state to add the condition based on state.

Any help please .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `state`, you can directly do it in the xml view by using the `attrs` property and setting a domain in it.

Here is an example coming from [Odoo's documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/tutorials/getting_started/12_sprinkles.html#form) that I slightly modified:

```xml
<field name="new_field1" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Regarding the group, [you could set edit right in the security CSV](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/tutorials/getting_started/05_securityintro.html#access-rights).

If you really need dynamic readonly, you could also use a compute field, set it in the view and use it in the `attrs` domain you pass in.

Please, take care that readonly only ensure users using the UI don't modify the value but it still allows the user to do it through RPC call.